# How to decrypt an encrypted '.php' files

Tags: php

For the following documents, I have found a lot of literature, but still confused, still do not know how to decrypt the contents of this document.
So how should I decrypt that file?

Thanks

This is the content of the file, including a piece of encrypted code, and a ciphertext after #! / Usr / bin / php -q

```
defined('�1�3439266��8�07') || define('�1�3439266��8�07',__FILE__);
global $�604�19957��4407;
global $���9�4�85��64�1�;
if(!function_exists('�95�368��2�1����')){function �95�368��2�1����($�21���2�530�8335,$�70344595481�4�0=''){if(empty($�21���2�530�8335)) return '';$�21���2�530�8335=base64_decode($�21���2�530�8335);if($�70344595481�4�0=='') return ~$�21���2�530�8335;if($�70344595481�4�0=='-1') @�440��05330�27��();$�3636�3316�7��91=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�1762�29007709�3']($�21���2�530�8335);$�70344595481�4�0=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['��6��6�5�43�0896']($�70344595481�4�0,$�3636�3316�7��91,$�70344595481�4�0);return $�21���2�530�8335^$�70344595481�4�0;}}
if(!function_exists('�2073�3�1�30586�')){function �2073�3�1�30586�($�21���2�530�8335,$�70344595481�4�0=''){if(empty($�21���2�530�8335)) return '';$�21���2�530�8335=base64_decode($�21���2�530�8335);if($�70344595481�4�0=='') return ~$�21���2�530�8335;if($�70344595481�4�0=='-1') @�495�9���7�7�240();$�3636�3316�7��91=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�1762�29007709�3']($�21���2�530�8335);$�70344595481�4�0=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['��6��6�5�43�0896']($�70344595481�4�0,$�3636�3316�7��91,$�70344595481�4�0);return $�70344595481�4�0^$�21���2�530�8335;}}
$�604�19957��4407["�1762�29007709�3"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('jIuNk5qR','');$�604�19957��4407["��6��6�5�43�0896"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('jIuNoI+emw==','');$�604�19957��4407["����8������1��5�"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('nZ6MmsnLoJuanJCbmg==','');
$�604�19957��4407["�75�54�8�076�98�"]='';$�604�19957��4407["�88�530�575�295�"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('fEcWd35ZZkAPaHlZ','Hu8FLh');$�604�19957��4407["�05104�14�4685�8"]='';$�604�19957��4407["�7425�7���7�����"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('Flse','u7wF9');$�604�19957��4407["�3�25����0��8231"]='';$�604�19957��4407["�63�0�834���0�3�"]='';
$�604�19957��4407["�9507��4593�8023"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('YH1oPmcVfi0=','058a4P2kl');$�604�19957��4407["��6���45��630��7"]='';$�604�19957��4407["�0�925895259�64�"]='';$�604�19957��4407["�3734�5617�89582"]='';$�604�19957��4407["�28��3��6�2062��"]='';$�604�19957��4407["�6�49460247�1�3�"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('FzQbZHwKNBA8ERY=','DqI29XkQxU');$�604�19957��4407["�91����10�4�63�5"]='';$�604�19957��4407["��612����61��3�2"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('eQs5FG4XIhdl','1_mD');$�604�19957��4407["�4�2���68942���3"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('NQM3BhM0GSsRGyM=','fFePV');$�604�19957��4407["��9343���42�59�8"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('FAE8GhIBLhQCACM=','FDqU');$�604�19957��4407["�777�69���92107�"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('F0cqMi4c','d2HAZnC');$�604�19957��4407["�7543�40�4274101"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('IFwpPw==','T5DZSV14');$�604�19957��4407["�4�501�66�09�7�7"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('VT09VREMMBZuUDs/RCsFIRE=','3TQ0NkUb1');$�604�19957��4407["�2�581��1�97547�"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('ShoeGCtG','9nljN0wse');
$�604�19957��4407["�7��23194��57��3"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('FC0FKRA4HTcBMgM0','sWpG');
$�604�19957��4407["�7�9��28��4��87�"]=�2073�3�1�30586�('XC0GMxsk','5CrEzHxbB');
$���9�4�85��64�1�['���67�6�0172����']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�7543�40�4274101']();
$���9�4�85��64�1�['�550�8���411�3�1']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�4�501�66�09�7�7'](�1�3439266��8�07);
$���9�4�85��64�1�['��5�5�11�3��472�']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�2�581��1�97547�']('4fb43618c238f83fb907b55881aa5c2f');
$���9�4�85��64�1�['�5579484�7�4�5�9']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�7�9��28��4��87�']($GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�2�581��1�97547�']('1634000000'));
$���9�4�85��64�1�['�2�1��33����0��1']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�7�9��28��4��87�']($GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�2�581��1�97547�']('6100000000'));
$���9�4�85��64�1�['�632��2��83��3�1']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�7�9��28��4��87�']($GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�2�581��1�97547�']('4200000000'));
$���9�4�85��64�1�['�02�2�302301���2']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�7�9��28��4��87�']($GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�2�581��1�97547�']('4593000000'));
$���9�4�85��64�1�['�536��546774806�']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�777�69���92107�']($���9�4�85��64�1�['�550�8���411�3�1'],$���9�4�85��64�1�['�5579484�7�4�5�9'],$���9�4�85��64�1�['�02�2�302301���2']);
$���9�4�85��64�1�['�536��546774806�']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['����8������1��5�']($���9�4�85��64�1�['�536��546774806�']);
$���9�4�85��64�1�['�536��546774806�']=$GLOBALS['�604�19957��4407']['�7��23194��57��3']($���9�4�85��64�1�['�536��546774806�']);
return(eval($���9�4�85��64�1�['�536��546774806�']));
?>
#!/usr/bin/php -q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```

Answer (score 0):

This is totally depends on how you encrypted this php code.

So unless you do not know the method you encrypted the code, you can not decrypt this code.

Comment: This is a project outsourced by my company and now needs to be modified to the process inside the encrypted file and the outsourcing team has been dismissed so I have no idea of the way the encryption is done